# Terminal opens new tab instead of new window with Command-N

Tags: macos, terminal

I dont know why but both Command-N and manually clicking open new window in the file menu of Terminal.app opens a new tab. Anyone encountered this before?

**How can I make Terminal.app open new windows instead of a new tab?**

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I use a blank keyboard (Das Keyboard Ultimate) and noticed that Option+N kept creating new tabs instead of new windows. Thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, and this was very frustrating when I noticed it since I only ever use tabs in a browser, not to mention opening the tab bar resizes the window >:O

Go into System Preferences -> Dock, then make sure that "Prefer tabs when opening documents" is NOT set to "Always".

[image]

Comment: Oh my this was bugging me for a long time because the only app I use which honors this setting is iterm2 so I thought it was an issue in that app. Thanks!

Comment: This behaviour changed between MacOS 10.12 and 10.13 by the way. I had this option set to Always in 10.12 and explicitly opening a new shell in a new window worked properly. This seems like a regression - why have two different commands if they're going to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: Oh my god, why apple, why ?!?!?!?!? This should be in terminal settings... whyyyy apple ?!?
Thank you djohns505 !!!!!!

Comment: Note for Big Sur users - this setting has moved to System Preferences -> General

Comment: Note for Ventura users - it was moved back under Desktop and Dock

Answer (score 14):

You can press Option-Command-N to open a window even if you set always open documents in tab in Dock preferences (this is handy).

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed to know to update my applescripts, all without changing my system settings.

Comment: I'm so used to Command-N to open new window, I really want to get back to that (as of Big Sur in 2021). There's already Command-T to open a new tab, and I would use that if I wanted that. The problem is I don't see Option-Command-N in the Terminal GUI menu so I don't know how to assign a Keyboard shortcut from the preference panel to that, since it keys into drop down menu names the App uses.

Comment: or hold option when clicking menu item.